# Plot many countries inside another

Tags: r, dictionary, projection, area

I want to show how big Brazilian Amazon Forest is, plotting different countries inside it. Like in this image:

[image]

To accomplish that, I loaded some shapefiles and changed their projection to one that would keep the areas proportional, like Cylindrical Equal Area:

```
library(rgdal)
countries <- readOGR("shp","TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3")
countries <- spTransform(countries,CRS("+proj=cea"))
amzLegal <- readOGR("shp","amazlegal")
amzLegal@proj4string <- CRS("+proj=longlat")
amzLegal <- spTransform(amzLegal,CRS("+proj=cea"))
plot(amzLegal)
FR <- countries[which(countries$NAME == "France"),]
for (i in 1:length(FR@polygons[[1]]@Polygons)) {
FR@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[i]]@coords[,1] = FR@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[i]]@coords[,1]-7180000
FR@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[i]]@coords[,2] = FR@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[i]]@coords[,2]-4930000
}
plot(FR,col="blue",add=T)
```

I'm getting this (without the lines, which I added later):

[image]

According to Google Earth, the red line is about 950 km (in France), the same measure of the black line (in Brazil). So of course the Cylindrical Equal Area is not the proper projection to use, since it enlarges the longitude and shrinks the latitude. What projection should I use, then? One that keeps shape AND size? I have also tried the Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area, but didn't work either. I like the Goode's Homolosine but it's not really a single projection, but a mix of different techniques. Here is a list of the possible projections: http://www.remotesensing.org/geotiff/proj_list/

EDIT: Following @CiaPan answer, I came to this function:

```
translate <- function(obj,x,y,ang=0,adiciona=T) {

maxLat <- -90
for (i in 1:length(obj@polygons[[1]]@Polygons)) {
    for (j in 1:nrow(obj@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[i]]@coords)) {
        lat <- obj@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[i]]@coords[j,2]
        if (lat > maxLat) {
            maxLat <- lat
            maxLon <- obj@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[i]]@coords[j,1]
        }
    }
}
lon0 <- maxLon*pi/180
lat0 <- maxLat*pi/180

y <- y*pi/180 # degrees to radians
ang <- ang*pi/180
x1 = 180
x2 = -180
y1 = 90
y2 = -90
for (i in 1:length(obj@polygons[[1]]@Polygons)) {
    for (j in 1:nrow(obj@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[i]]@coords)) {
        lon <- obj@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[i]]@coords[j,1]*pi/180 - lon0      #1 V to Greenwich
        lat <- obj@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[i]]@coords[j,2]*pi/180

        X <- cos(lon)*cos(lat)                 #2 Cartesian coords
        Y <- sin(lon)*cos(lat)
        Z <- sin(lat)

        X0 <- X
        X <- X0*cos(lat0) - Z*sin(-lat0)       #3 V to Equator
        Z <- X0*sin(-lat0) + Z*cos(lat0)

        Y0 <- Y
        Y <- Y0*cos(ang) - Z*sin(ang)          #4 rotate by ang
        Z <- Y0*sin(ang) + Z*cos(ang)

        X0 <- X
        X <- X0*cos(y) - Z*sin(y)              #5 V to y
        Z <- X0*sin(y) + Z*cos(y)

        lat <- asin(Z)                         #6
        lon <- asin(Y/cos(lat))*180/pi + x
        lat <- lat*180/pi

        if (lon < x1) { x1 <- lon }            #bbox
        if (lon > x2) { x2 <- lon }
        if (lat < y1) { y1 <- lat }
        if (lat > y2) { y2 <- lat }

        obj@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[i]]@coords[j,1] <- lon
        obj@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[i]]@coords[j,2] <- lat
    }
}
obj@bbox[1,1] <- x1
obj@bbox[1,2] <- x2
obj@bbox[2,1] <- y1
obj@bbox[2,2] <- y2

plot(obj,col="red",border="black",add=adiciona)

}
```

Where obj is a spatialPolygons object, x and y are long and lat of destination. The function translates and plot the object. Usage can be:

```
library(rgdal)
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
countries <- readOGR("shp","TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3",encoding="UTF-8")
plot(countries,col=rgb(1,0.8,0.4))
translate(countries[which(countries$NAME == "France"),],-60,0,0,T)
```

where the shapefile was downloaded from [here](http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.zip). Thank you all!

Comment: IMVHO it would be better to slide the geographic contours over the sphere (possibly with some rotations) to fit inside the Amazonian borders and then project them all with any chosen method into a plane.

Comment: You mean do this step (FR@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[i]]@coords[,1] = FR@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[i]]@coords[,1]-7180000) for the entire European continent, and only then project them? If that's what you suggested, it won't work, because 1 degree in a high latitude is bigger than 1 degree close to the Equator line.

Comment: Anyway, what surprises me is how small is France in the first map above! Is it a different projection, or just a mistake?

Comment: I said 'slide over the *sphere*' not a *plane*, meaning applying 3D rotations to 3D vectors describing countries countours' vertices in a 3D space, in which the Earth sphere exists. Adding a constant to a planar or geographical coortinate is nonsense, if you add to lattitude you might go over the Earth pole!

Comment: Well, I have no idea how to do that. Can you suggest any tutorial, please? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First assuming your countries' borders are given with geographic (φ,λ) coordinates – if they are (x,y) in some cartographic projection, you'd have to transform them back to the geographic system.

Choose one vertex, possibly the northernmost: V(φ0, λ0) and decide where it shall finally land in the amazonian region: (φ1,λ1) and how much rotated: θ. You'll achieve it in several simple steps:

1. Slide the shape along the circle of latitude, so that V lands on the Greenwich meridian – you do this subtracting λ0 from all longitudes:
   λ := λ - λ0
2. Next calculate Cartesian coordinates of all vertices of the slided border (assuming the Earth surface is a sphere, not an ellipsoid let alone the geoid, and taking the Earth radius as a length unit):
   X := cos λ cos φ
   Y := sin λ cos φ
   Z := sin φ
3. Slide the shape to the south, so that V lands on the equator. You do this rotating all vertices in XZ plane by the (−φ0) angle:
   X := X cos(φ0) − Z sin(−φ0)
   Z := X sin(−φ0) + Z cos(φ0)
4. Rotate the border by θ around the V vertex, which currently lays on Atlantic Ocean at geographic coordinates (0,0) – this is a plane YZ rotation:
   Y := Y cos(θ) − Z sin(θ)
   Z := Y sin(θ) + Z cos(θ)
5. Now the country border is ready to travel to Amazonian Forests. First slide it south along the Greenwich meridian to the desired latitude (plane XZ rotation by φ1 – note φ1 is negative, as it denotes the southern hemisphere):
   X := X cos(φ1) − Z sin(φ1)
   Z := X sin(φ1) + Z cos(φ1)
6. then transform coordinates to geographic system:
   φ :=  asin(Z)
   λ := asin(Y/cos(φ))
7. and finally slide them west to the South America
   λ = λ + λ1
8. Done. At least I hope so... ;)

**EDIT**

You also might do step 2. before 1. and step 6. after 7.
Then, of course, sliding the border along the circle of latitude would not be as simple as λ := λ + const., it would have to be computed as a XY-plane rotation, similar to steps 3. through 5. This way, however, ALL transformations will be performed in a similar way, which you can describe as a matrix multiplication. And matrix multiplication is associative, so all coefficient matrices can be calculated in advance and multiplied together (in the proper order!), then you transform each vertex of a border with a single matrix multiplication.

Once you processed all the countries just plot them all to see if they intersect. In such case tune the destination points and θ rotations until all borders fit the Amazonian jungle contour with no collision. Hope that  helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, @CiaPan! I'm implementing it now. You took the northernmost point by chance? I got the first coordinate in my first polygon, not the northernmost, and I'm shifting it exactly to Equator line, getting a problem in asin(Y/cos(lat)), a few times Y > cos(lat)...

Comment: 1) Generally it doesn't matter which point you choose, it might be some 'country center' point as well. I chose the northernmost just because I had a picture in my head of countries being laid out somewhat like text in the page, from upper left region to the right, then downwards, and a reference point at the northern edge would make the positioning easiest.

Comment: 2) Certainly, due to arithmetic errors, rounding and truncating, some values may go past the `asin`/`acos` domain. You'll have to test that in advance and 'drag' them back to the allowed interval. Or do not call trigonometric function in such case but directly substitute the known result instead.

Comment: Yes, it works. Actually it was mine fault about converting degrees/radians... thanks a lot!

Comment: Well @CiaPan, I thought it was working, but it's not yet, properly. Your third step has something wrong X <- X*cos(lat0) + Z*sin(lat0); Z <- Z*cos(lat0) - X*sin(lat0) I'm not doing steps 4 or 5, so all countries should fall in Equator line. But they're falling in the opposite hemisphere, according to a non-linear relation to the original latitude (I'll edit the question to show you how).

Comment: I got it! In your third step, the first line changes the value of X used in the second line. To prevent this I created a X0 receiving the original X and used it in the second line... Thank you!!

Comment: Ahh, I thought it was clear the assignments take place 'simultaneously', that is you calculate some new X,Z coordinates from some old X,Z coordinates. I might have written explicitly Xnew,Znew on the left and Xold,Zold on the right-hand side of the assignments, which would prevent confusion. Sorry about that. Similar problem may arise in other steps.

Comment: Don't worry. Your help was unmeasurable!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using trying different projections, but then plot Tissot’s ellipses on the maps you generate (first two links below). You could visually inspect the maps and pick countries that have *similar* distortion.

If you just want to compare visually, any interrupted projection would be best. The only problem is that there are a lot of discontinuities. Each time you want to create an image of a country, you shift the projection until the entire country (or as much as you can get) is without discontinuity.
Just from scanning through your list, I don't see any that I recognize as interrupted. If you are not strictly limited to these projections, I recommend Goode's Homolosine as it puts the discontinuities in oceans.

Ref:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tissot%27s_Indicatrix
- https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5068/how-to-create-an-accurate-tissot-indicatrix
- http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/proc98/PROCEED/TO850/PAP844/P844.HTM

This software (free), allows you to compare (& plot tissot's ellipses) on many different projections: 
http://www.flexprojector.com/

Comment: It seems the way to go is Goode's Homolosine, but it doesn't seem easy at all! I'll try it. Thank you!

Comment: I've never worked with this projection in R, so I can't help with specific code, but this seems to be a coherent example that you could draw from: http://www.r-forge.r-project.org/forum/forum.php?max_rows=25&style=nested&offset=160&forum_id=962&group_id=294