# Error in subtraction with code pasted from the clipboard

Tags: r

OK, simplifying it:

```
lat0 <- 42.61527
X <- 0.2023649
Z <- -0.9793102
```

Why does this give an error:

```
X <- X*cos(lat0) − Z*sin(-lat0)
## Error: unexpected input in "X <- X*cos(lat0) �"
```

and this doesn't?

```
X <- X*cos(42.61527) - Z*sin(-42.61527)
```

Here is the platform and R version:

```
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32
version.string R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
```

---

I'm trying to implement [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23818268/1086511)

Comment: It looks like an esoteric error related to something strange in your R session or workspace. Can you reproduce it in a clean R session? (And your example is not reproducible. It gives error on first line: cannot find function readOGR. I know you gave a link but it is better to copy all relevant parts e.g library (xyz) etc)

Comment: I can't try your example without a definition of `Z`

Comment: Please give us a reproducible example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry. I added the library(rgdal) and the definition of Z in the first part. Thank you! I'll try in a clean R session.

Comment: Look the comments below. It looks like the R Console translate the hex string e2 88 92 into a minus sign... thank you all!

Comment: @Rodrigo I edited your question to remove the original code, add the error message that I get from your example, and try to give a better title.  Feel free to roll back or edit further, as you wish.

Comment: That's not the error I was getting. So I think we can delete this question...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing that looks like a minus sign between `X*cos(lat0)` and `Z*sin(-lat0)`, is not a minus sign:

```
X <- X*cos(lat0) − Z*sin(-lat0)
```

Here is a hex dump of this text:

```
0000000  sp   X  sp   <   -  sp   X   *   c   o   s   (   l   a   t   0
         20  58  20  3c  2d  20  58  2a  63  6f  73  28  6c  61  74  30
0000020   )  sp   b  bs dc2  sp   Z   *   s   i   n   (   -   l   a   t
         29  20  e2  88  92  20  5a  2a  73  69  6e  28  2d  6c  61  74
0000040   0   )  nl
         30  29  0a
0000043
```

What should be a `-` sign is the unicode character represented by the hex string `e2 88 92`

Comment: Very strange. If I select all the X*cos(lat0) − Z*sin(-lat0) and run the selection, it gives me the 1 as result. If I run the whole line including the X <- , it crashes again. And it crashes only in the script window, not in the R Console...

Comment: Note that in the lines with a problem, the hyphen is longer than a normal minus sign:  `-` vs `−`

Comment: Yes, it is. Strange that the R Console made the substitution automatically... Thank you!

Comment: @MatthewLundberg: Actually, THAT was a minus sign, a sign resulting from HTML `&minus;` entity. :)

Comment: Sorry everybody (especially Rodrigo!), when responding in that thread I used HTML `&minus;` instead of ASCII dash, because the minus is the same width as standard plus character. I had no idea it will cause some problem when copied-and-pasted as an expression to the R interpreter.